# Excel pivot table to python table

Tags: python, dataframe, pivot-table

Suppose I want to convert the following pivot table in excel to a table using python:

[image]

Suppose the green cells represent weight. How do I convert this to a table with 3 columns Height, Age, Weight using python?

I want to get a table like this in Python:

[image]

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Your question has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46154843/how-to-read-pivot-table-from-excel-document-in-python-pandas

Comment: @pakpe although the output in that question is the same the initial table is different. I understand how that works but this I feel is different

Comment: @user81883 I am didn't close it. but it is called Duplicate which means the two question are similar. :)

Comment: @KevinM.Mansour The question is closed now. It's ok because I got the answer I was looking for below :) Hope the moderators understand that not all "similar" questions have the same answer.

Comment: Actually they are not moderators. They are community. Anyway have a Great Day. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html#pandas-melt) to "un-pivot" the table:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx') \
    .melt(id_vars='Height/Age', var_name='Age', value_name='Weight') \
    .rename(columns={'Height/Age': 'Height'}) \
    .sort_values('Height') \
    .reset_index(drop=True)

print(df)
```

`df`:

```
   Height Age  Weight
0       3  15     134
1       3  20     120
2       3  25      98
3       4  15     134
4       4  20     122
5       4  25     150
6       5  15     200
7       5  20     198
8       5  25     145
```